# Concatenate strings from different xsl nodes in iReport

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports, datasource, ireport

Let's suppose the following XML used as a datasource in a Jasper report:

```
<B>
    <C>text1</C>
    <C>text2</C>
    <C>text3</C>

    <List number="1">
        <ListElement1 key="k1" />
        <ListElement2 key="k2" />
    </List>

    <List number="2 />
</B>

<B></B>
<B></B>
```

In a report list element which lists  nodes, i'd like to print C texts concatenated as "text1, text2, text3", but there are some problems:

- It is no possible to use Xpath functions in datasets.
- Also, using the Report query in *iReport* doesn't let me define fields from relative paths, such as ../../C from List.

Is there a straightforward way to do this? I mean, not using subReports and anything like that.